# Are photos on facebook ever actually deleted from facebook database?

Tags: facebook, image

If I delete a photo from facebook, does the link remain valid? If some photo was deleted, but I still have the link (possibly in a JSON file) will I be able to post the photo again based on the link saved in my JSON file? Also will photos and videos on facebook keep their addresses, or might they be changed over time?

Comment: Have you tried deleting a photo from facebook and then try to access the photo via the link?

Comment: Yes, I have, and the link remains valid, but I am not sure if the link will still be valid over an extended period of time. Of course, this indicates that the simple action of deleting a photo doesn't also remove it from the database. But does it make it more likely to be removed or moved to another address after some time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this Ars Technica article from August 16, 2012:

http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/08/facebook-finally-changes-photo-deletion-policy-after-3-years-of-reporting/

Three years later, deleting your photos on Facebook now actually works
After years of photo hoarding, Facebook now deletes user photos within 30 days.

I am sure if you wanted to follow up with the reporter who wrote the story, she would respond. Her page is located here:  http://arstechnica.com/author/jacqui-cheng/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I want to help the user get back his/her photos if he/she accidentally deleted them and might not have them anymore on the computer, and I needed to know whether the link would be available in any conditions or if I should tell the user that the deleted photos can be recuperated until a certain time passes